# addaction hook cause redirection problem

Tags: hooks, actions

I have added the hook in my wp functions:

```
add_action('pa_taxname_edit_form_fields',  'woocom_edit_attribute_chk_field', 10, 2);


function woocom_edit_attribute_chk_field($term, $taxonomy) {
     //////////////// My code here

}

add_action('edited_term', 'woocom_attribute_chk_field_save', 10, 3);

function woocom_attribute_chk_field_save($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {
                metas = $_pOST['aa'];
                 update_woocommerce_term_meta($term_id,'_designparent', $metas);

}
```

Here the field saved successfully. But it is not redirect to the  edit-tags.php. Here the query strings are missed.

Actual url = `edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=pa_taxname&tag_ID=1036&post_type=product`

But after save the page redirected to  `edit-tags.php` (Query strings missed)

Comment: Are you doing anything with `wp_redirect`?

Comment: Unless you are doing a `wp_redirect`, or any type of `remove_query_arg` type thing, it will redirect automatically, no need to add you own in.

Comment: $_pOST['aa']; correct it and try

Comment: In the first line of the function, metas is also missing the $ at the beginning

Comment: I didn't do anything with wp_redirect and remove_query_arg. But it didn't redirect. Is there any alternate way?